# Парсинг методов

Tags: java, парсер

Есть ли способы вытащить метод из кода (со всеми модификаторами и параметрами) без использования стороннего по?

Есть файл с расширением .java, в нём есть, к примеру, один метод

```
static int getSum(int a, int b){
//тело
}
```

Из этого файла нужно взять этот метод и вывести его в текстовый файл в формате

```
static int getSum(int a, int b){
}
```

Comment: мммм. не очень понятен вопрос. как понять вытащить ?

Comment: Почему вы не хотите использовать готовую библиотеку?

Comment: @ЦовакСаакян взять файл, прочитать его, найти все методы в нём, вывести все найденные методы во второй файл, как это показано на моём примере.

Comment: @enzo спортивный интерес, новые знания

Comment: Если предположить, что файл хорошо отформатирован, то можно вытащить регулярками. Если нет, то честно парсить файл.

Comment: Без рефлексии и библиотек только парсить.... долго и мучительно)

Comment: а нельзя вызвать компилятор или иную утилиту из `jdk`? Может `javadoc` с параметрами какими-то?

Comment: @pavel чтоб использовать javadoc, нужно чтоб он там был.... а если его нет? Просто накиданы интуитивно понятные методы. Да и просто.

Answer (score 5):

Конечно можно. Этот способ называется рефлексия (Reflection)

`Reflection`  в *Java* используется для просмотра информации о классах, интерфейсах, методах, полях, конструкторах, аннотациях во время выполнения java программ.
При этом знать названия исследуемых элементов заранее не обязательно.

Все классы для работы с `reflection` расположены в пакете `java.lang.reflect`.

С помощью рефлексии можно

- Получить информацию о модификаторах класса, полях, методах, константах, конструкторах и суперклассах.
- Узнать/определить класс объекта
- Получить и установить значение поля объекта по имени.
- Вызвать метод объекта по имени.
- Выяснить, какие методы принадлежат реализуемому интерфейсу/интерфейсам.
  Создать экземпляр класса, причем имя класса неизвестно до момента выполнения программы.

  ```
  MyClass obj = new MyClass(); // <--- это класс, который будем просматривать

  Class c = obj.getClass(); // Получение объекта типа Class
  Method[] methods = c.getDeclaredMethods(); // возвращаем все методы класса не зависимо от типа доступа

  for (Method method : methods) {
      System.out.println("Имя: " + method.getName());
      System.out.println("Возвращаемый тип: " + method.getReturnType().getName());

      Class[] paramTypes = method.getParameterTypes(); // берем параметры метода
      System.out.print("Типы параметров: ");

      for (Class paramType : paramTypes) {
          System.out.print(" " + paramType.getName());
      }

      System.out.println();
      System.out.println("------------------------");
  }
  ```

Вместо

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass(); // <--- это класс, который будем просматривать
Class c = obj.getClass(); // Получение объекта типа Class
```

Можно писать:

```
Class obj = MyClass.class;
```

Т.е. не нужно создавать экземпляр класса (который может вызвать конструктор и провернуть неизвестные манипуляции), а мы уже знаем в момент компиляции  какого типа он будет.

Если мы не знаем имя класса на момент компиляции, но знаем во время выполнения приложения, то можно использовать метод `forName()`, чтобы получить объект `Class`.

```
Class obj = Class.forName("com.test.classes.MyClass");
```

Comment: вопрос вроде бы "про вытащить из кода", а не из скомпилированного класса.

Comment: @Nofate  мм. да? то есть чтение файла? ну если автор это подтвердит - удалю.

Comment: а нельзя дёрнуть компилятор или другую утилиту из `jdk`? Или у них нет опции вернуть методы файла?

Comment: Да, мне нужно сделать это до выполнения самой программы. Но за информацию спасибо.

Comment: @quzty в смысле до выполнения самой программы?Это я что-то не очень понял...... ............ у вас класс, в котором написаны методы и прочее. просто лежит как текстовый файл, типа `text.txt` и из него распарсить? или у вас есть какой-то класс `MyClass.java` и из него надо доставать всё?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский да, есть класс типа MyClass.java изначально.

Comment: А можно получить `Class c`, не создавая экземпляр `MyClass`? А то мало ли чего он в своём конструкторе вытворяет...

Comment: @VladD да. дописал. `MyClass.class;` не должен вызвать конструктор

Answer (score 2):

Скачайте Java Parser [отсюда](http://javaparser.org/)

Потом нужно написать следующий код, он поможет нам получить `CompilationUnit`

```
        InputStream in = null;
        CompilationUnit cu = null;
        try
        {
                in = new SEDInputStream(filename);
                cu = JavaParser.parse(in);
        }
        catch(ParseException x)
        {
             // обработка исключений парсера
        }
        finally
        {
              in.close();
        }
        return cu;
```

Заметьте: SEDInputStream это подкласс input stream. Вы можете использовать FileInputStream, если пожелаете.

---

Теперь нужно создать visitor. Ваш visitor будет простым, т.к. вас интересуют только методы.

```
  public class MethodVisitor extends VoidVisitorAdapter
  {
    public void visit(MethodDeclaration n, Object arg)
    {
         // Информация о методах извлекается здесь
         // Положите её в HasMap
    }
  }
```

---

Для вызова visitor, сделайте так

```
MethodVisitor visitor = new MethodVisitor();
visitor.visit(cu, null);
```

---

[Дубликат](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2206065/java-parse-java-source-code-extract-methods) вопроса на StackOverflow

Comment: Вопрос был **без использования стороннего по**

Comment: Какой смысл писать свой велосипед, если уже есть парсер с необходимым функционалом?

Comment: `спортивный интерес, новые знания`  http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/539375/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2/539377#comment680689_539375   ......так что ваш ответ в не туда) Не все так просто)))

Comment: @АлексейШиманский это поправка превращает вопрос в "как мне написать с нуля парсер java (дайте код)" и делает его кандидатом на закрытие

Comment: @zRrr ну да. вперед и с песней)