# Получить экземпляр интерфейса через сабкласс, используя рефлексию

Tags: java, рефлексия

Есть класс, в конструктор которого требуется передать интерфейс. Как получить его экземпляр, если имеется класс, реализующий этот интерфейс и я могу создать экземпляр такого класса.

P.S Рефлексия

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/539377/191482 или http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/594811/191482 подойдет?

Comment: про юзабилити Reflection API я знаю) я не пойму как получить инстанс интерфейса

Comment: можно ли использовать инстанс не интерфейса а класса  его наследующего?

Comment: `как получить инстанс интерфейса` – никак. А задача пока не очень ясна. Попробуйте добавить примерной код.

Comment: Так и создайте: `Animal animal = new Dog();`. `Animal` - интерфейс, `Dog` - класс, его реализующий. Для чего здесь нужна рефлексия?

Comment: Сделать его сиглтоном и вызывать посредством newInstace()

Comment: Код до этого момента написан на рефлексии.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Создавать объект через рефлексию дороже, чем простым вызовом конструктора, поэтому если есть возможность, старайтесь избегать рефлексию.

Что касается самого вопроса, то правильно ли я понимаю, что нужно создать объект через конструктор, аргументом которого является интерфейс?

```
public class Person {
    private final int size;

    public Person(List list) {
        size = list != null ? list.size() : 0;
    }

    public int getSize() {
        return size;
    }
}
```

В таком случае просто берём нужный конструктор, подставляем реализацию в качестве аргумента и создаём объект.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException, IllegalAccessException, InvocationTargetException, InstantiationException {
    Class clazz = Person.class;
    Constructor constructor = clazz.getConstructor(List.class);
    Person person = (Person) constructor.newInstance(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
    System.out.println(person.getSize());
}
```